# Last number match dont show all values

Tags: excel

right now I have this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$14;SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($A$2:$A$14)*(A1=$A$2:$A$14))-1))
```

And this is how my excel looks:

```
123 10
123 20
123 20
455 55
455 554
```

So what I want is that when in column C i putt the formula it shows blank cells unless it is the last value

So the first 123 shouldt show anything but the last should show 123 should show 20.

Comment: So would Column C be "blank, blank, 20, blank, 554"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1),B1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: I would want to try it But since i live in another country i have the ; as seperator

Do you by any change know how to do this:
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A;A1)=COUNTIF($A$1:A1;A1);B1,'"")

I have this but after the B1 it fails also if i putt an ; there